# Not getting output using freopen in c++ :-vs code showing

Tags: c++, freopen

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
#ifdef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << n + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

while using freopen for input and output result of my program in c++ in vs code i am not getting ouput in ouput.txt file.for eg:i created a program to enter a no. n and ouput n+1.
But while entering 24 in input i am geting 32765 in ouput.txt but in my terminal i am getting 25 that's it.and by compiling the program again and again 32765 changes to 32767 and so on.

Comment: using same code not getting output in ouput.txt

Comment: @162_NiteshSingh you need to make file called input.txt and just type any int.

Comment: Should `#ifdef ONLINE_JUDGE` be `#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE`?

Comment: Have you tried printing the errors, if any, from `freopen()`?

Comment: @coderx64 input.txt is working but ouput.txt is not working

Comment: @AlanBirtles tried #ifndef that also but no result and also showing no error working in terminal but not in output.txt

Answer (score 0):

When reading files this way, make sure the file you are referring to is in the present working directory of the terminal.

---

In the following folder structure

```
ParentFolder
├── Folder1
│   ├── code
│   ├── code.cpp
│   └── input.txt
└── Folder2
    └── input.txt
```

If your present working directory is `Folder2`, then input file used will be `ParentFolder/Folder2/input.txt` **even if you have an input file in the same folder as your code and executable, as relative paths are decided using terminals working directory.**

And naturally, if the file doesn't exist/can't be opened, you will get grabage numbers.